# Pandas groupby with dropna set to True generating wrong output

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

In the following snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
        "b": [1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, 2, 1, 2, np.nan, 1]
    }
)
df_again = df.groupby("b", dropna=False).apply(lambda x: x)
```

I was expecting `df` and `df_again` to be identical. But they are not:

```
df
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  1.0
3  4  NaN
4  5  2.0
5  6  1.0
6  7  2.0
7  8  NaN
8  9  1.0

df_again
   a    b
0  1  1.0
2  3  1.0
4  5  2.0
5  6  1.0
6  7  2.0
8  9  1.0
```

Now, if I tweak slightly the lambda expression to "see" what is going on by
`df.groupby("b", dropna=False).apply(lambda x: print(x))` I can actually visualize that also the portion of the `df` where `b` was `NaN` was processed.

What am I missing here?
(Using pandas 1.3.1 and numpy 1.20.3)

Comment: In my opinion `None` and `NaN` should be processed equal, maybe it is bug or not documented.

Comment: They should because "b" was "casted" to float. To avoid discussion around this I edited the question to only use the `np.nan` right from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug introduced in pandas 1.2.0 as described [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43205) and was solved [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/43236).

Answer (score 1):

It's because `None` and `None` are the same thing:

```
>>> None == None
True
>>>
```

You have to use `np.nan`:

```
>>> np.NaN == np.NaN
False
>>>
```

So try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
        "b": [1, np.NaN, 1, np.NaN, 2, 1, 2, np.NaN, 1]
    }
)
df_again = df.groupby("b", dropna=False).apply(lambda x: x)
```

Now `df` and `df_again` would be the same:

```
>>> df
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  1.0
3  4  NaN
4  5  2.0
5  6  1.0
6  7  2.0
7  8  NaN
8  9  1.0
>>> df_again
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  2  NaN
2  3  1.0
3  4  NaN
4  5  2.0
5  6  1.0
6  7  2.0
7  8  NaN
8  9  1.0
>>> df.equals(df_again)
True
>>>
```

Comment: `It's because None and None are the same thing:` Agree, but in pandas processing `None` and `NaN` is same.

Comment: @jezrael True, but for this case it is required for `NaN` because `groupby`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and in fact this is what I was getting before I updated pandas. I just repeated all the steps and still get the exact same undesired output (I edited my question with the versions of the packages used)

Comment: Sure, but if use `dropna` - it remove `None` or `NaN`

Comment: Btww, if use `df_again = df.groupby("b", dropna=False).apply(lambda x: x)` with `None` it not working for you in last pandas version?

Comment: It was... and that was pandas 1.1.3.

Comment: No it doesn't. I updated the question to explicitly construct the `df` with `np.nan` now.

Comment: @U12-Forward - What is your pandas version?

Comment: @jezrael 1.1.13

Comment: @U12-Forward - Ya, problem solved, in last version not working, in previous yes.

Comment: @jezrael Oh yeah!

Comment: So it's a bug ?

Comment: @deponovo Possible

Comment: Is any of you a pandas dev or should I go through https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues?

Comment: @deponovo - Best is use link above for post issue, I am not dev.

Comment: @all Done. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43205

Comment: @jezrael Just pinging you that deponovo posted this bug :)

Comment: @U12-Forward - I am not dev ;)

Comment: @jezrael haha you should be :D