# Keep NaN groups when using GroupBy apply

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I'm looking to keep the structure when using apply on a GroupBy object where some groups are NaN. Using dropna=False does not appear to help, NaN groups are still lost with apply.

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a', 'a', np.nan, 'b', 'b'], ['t', 'u', np.nan, 'w', 'y']],
                                names=['level1', 'level2'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [0, np.nan, np.nan, 3, 4]}, mux)
df

                col
level1  level2  
a       t       0.0
        u       NaN
NaN     NaN     NaN
b       w       3.0
        y       4.0

df = df.groupby(['level2'], dropna=False).apply(lambda x: x)
df

               col
level1  level2  
a       t      0.0
        u      NaN
b       w      3.0
        y      4.0
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68918019/pandas-groupby-with-dropna-set-to-true/68918101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this is more like a bug for call the index without `level`

```
out = df.groupby(level='level2', dropna=False).apply(lambda x: x)
Out[706]: 
               col
level1 level2     
a      t       0.0
       u       NaN
b      w       3.0
       y       4.0
NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to replace np.NaN with string "NaN" then apply groupby.